# 404 - File or directory not found. Diffrent result in local and server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404, windows-server

On case requested page doesn't exist, trying to send this code:

CodeBehind: `Response.StatusCode = 404;`

View: `<h1>page Not found</h1>`

This code works fine in local system, but when I try to upload the whole code and web.config on server. It's shows error:

[image]

Am I missing something on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```